# Coordinate transformations: PGFPlots to and from PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I scale a calculated length to the appropriate axis scale? In this example I would expect `2`.

See below.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}

    % Random plot
    \addplot {x};

    \coordinate (point1) at (axis cs:0,0);
    \coordinate (point2) at (axis cs:2,-4);

    \draw[red] (point1) -- (point2);

    \draw[black]
    let
    \p1 = (point1),
    \p2 = (point2),
    \n1={abs(\x{2}-\x{1})}
    in
    node at (axis cs:-2,4) {some x distance=\n1};    

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image: Imgur]

I tried to re-scale the length using `\pgfplotsunitxlength` (in this example, `0.4`), but that does not seem to be the correct transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two distinct transformations in place: one is the unit vector length of PGF (which is given as `\pgfplotsunitxlength`). The other is an affine linear map which rescales the input coordinates into the realm of PGF (i.e. into the range of -16384 .. 16384).

The second is hitting you here.

There are basically two approaches to deal with them: the first is to simply add `disabledatascaling` to the axis. As the name suggests, this turns of the second map and your approach with `\pgfplotsunitxlength` is correct. The second approach is the bottom remark of @John: to compute the scaling offset manually (I mean his `\unitx` variable).

I recommind using `disabledatascaling` for two reasons:

1. it is relatively simple
2. the other solution sounds as if it is more general, but unfortunately, it runs into unexpected problems: as soon as you really have a huge data range (scale everything with `1e4`, for example), it will break. The PGF math parser simply cannot cope with anything which exceeds this range.

The example becomes

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
        disabledatascaling,
    ]


    % Random plot
    \addplot {x};

    \coordinate (point1) at (axis cs:0,0);
    \coordinate (point2) at (axis cs:2,-4);

    \draw[red] (point1) -- (point2);

    \draw[black]
    let
    \p1 = (point1),
    \p2 = (point2),
    \n1={abs(\x{2}-\x{1})/\pgfplotsunitxlength}
    in
    node at (axis cs:-2,4) {some x distance=\n1};    


    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

The impact of using `disabledatascaling` is that your data range is limited to numbers in the range -16384 .. +16384 and they must not be smaller than 0.001. In addition, the arithmetic precision will drop rapidly once number become small (say: smaller than 0.01). As a rule of thumb, you can safely use `disabledatascaling` if your numbers are "small natural number". The solution is inadequate once you have huge numbers or very very small ones.

What you really need is a general way to transform a TikZ/PGF coordinate back to the original pgfplots points and do some arithmetics on them (using an advanced number range as in the floating point unit of PGF). Pgfplots currently has no public API for this inverse transformation (it would involve the inverse of `transformdirectionx`). This, in turn, would be a feature request for pgfplots.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. What are the ramifications of `disabledatascaling`? Plots are limited in scale to TeX dimensions? Can I have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: @kadrach right ... I have deleted the explaining sentence somewhere in the middle of refining the text, but apparently, I forgot to paste it in the correct place. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be off by a factor of 100.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\dist}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}


    % Random plot
    \addplot {x};

    \coordinate (point1) at (axis cs:0,0);
    \coordinate (point2) at (axis cs:2,-4);

    \draw[red] (point1) -- (point2);

    \pgfplotsextra{
      \pgfextractx{\dist}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{point1}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{point2}{center}}}
      \pgfmathparse{0.01\dist/\pgfplotsunitxlength}
      \global\let\text=\pgfmathresult
    }
    \end{axis}
   \node[above right] {\text};

\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

I've always just computed the value directly:

```
\newlength{\unitx}

\pgfplotsextra{% delay until \end{axis}
  \pgfextractx{\unitx}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfplotspointaxisxy{0}{0}}{\pgfplotspointaxisxy{1}{1}}}
  \global\unitx=\unitx
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed work, but how does this factor come about. How can I achieve this without hard coding a factor of 100? I'll leave this question open for a while longer.

Answer (score 2):

With the release of PGFPlots v1.16 it is now possible to store (axis)
coordinates with `\pgfplotspointgetcoordinates` in `data point`, which then
can be called by `\pgfkeysvalueof` or `\pgfkeysgetvalue`. With this it is possible to add the labels you want.

For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}

        % Random plot
        \addplot {x};

        \coordinate (point1) at (axis cs:0,0);
        \coordinate (point2) at (axis cs:2,-4);

        \draw [red] (point1) -- (point2);

        \node [align=left,anchor=north west] at (axis cs:-6,4) {
            the $x$ distance \\ (in axis coordinates) is
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
            % using `\pgfplotspointgetcoordinates' stores the (axis)
            % coordinates in `data point' which then can be called by
            % `\pgfkeysvalueof'
                \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(point1)}
                    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/data point/x}{\xOne}%
                \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(point2)}
                    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/data point/x}{\xTwo}%
                \pgfmathparse{\xTwo-\xOne}
                $\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}$
            % -----------------------------------------------------------------
        };

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]