# Pgfplots: how to have "let" retrieve coordinates in the axis coordinate system?

Tags: pgfplots, tikz-calc

This is a continuation of my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434552/tikz-display-coordinate-of-node-using-let-command), but now I want to use pgfplots.

In an axis environment, I add a node using the axes coordinate system.
I would like to use `let` to retrieve the coordinates of a node **in the axes coordinate system**.

In the example below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=10]
            \node [circle,fill,inner sep=2pt]  (d1) at (axis cs:4,2) {};
            \draw let \p1=(d1) in (d1) coordinate[label=below:\x1]{} ;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The label, which should give me the horizontal coordinate of the node, currently reads: 77.999988pt.

[image]

Where does that number come from?

Since the node is placed at (4,2), I would like instead get the label as 4 times 28.45274pt = 113.81096pt. (I would then transform it for display.)

Comment: I guess these are absolute coordinates and pgfplots does some rescaling. You can check this by adjusting the `width`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `\pgfplotspointgetcoordinate` command to extract the *x* and *y* coordinates of a given coordinate/node. Is that what you are searching for?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=10]
            \node [
                circle,
                fill,
                inner sep=2pt,
                pin=above:{
                    \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(d1)}
                    $(\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}},
                    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{
                    \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}})$
                },
            ]  (d1) at (axis cs:4,2) {};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: This is great. For future readers, I just want to point out that retrieving the coordinates can also be done for a node previously defined. `\node   (d2) at (axis cs:5,7) {};
 \coordinate [
  pin=above:{
  \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(d2)}
  $(\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{
   \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}},
  \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]{
   \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}})$
  }
 ] () at (d2);` works too.

Comment: This is true. I just marked this question being a duplicate where you can also see this in action.

Comment: Could you confirm that \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates only works within the axis environment? If so, is it possible to store their result and use them outside the axis environment?

Comment: I would guess so for the first question. For the second have a look at the command `\Getxycoords` in e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426245/95441. With that you can globally store the coordinates in custom commands and use it "everywhere", also outside the `tikzpicture` environment.