# PGFplots: extract coordinates, assign to global with dynamic name

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, intersections

I would like to loop over nodes, extract their coordinates in the axis coordinate system, and assign these to dynamically named macros. (This is a followup on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435282/pgfplots-how-to-have-let-retrieve-coordinates-in-the-axis-coordinate-system) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434552/tikz-display-coordinate-of-node-using-let-command).)

Following this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420498/extract-convert-store-and-reuse-x-y-coordinate-components/426245#426245), I define a function `\Getxycoords` that retrieves the coordinates in the axis cs of a node, and assign it to a global macro.

I would like to be able to do this for several points in a loop.

In the MWE, I define three nodes da, db, and dc. I'd like to store their coordinates (in the axis system) as \Xa, \Ya, \Xb, \Yb, \Xc, \Yc, using a loop. Unfortunately, I do not know how to pass a dynamic global name as the second and third arguments to the `\Getxycoords` function

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[
%border=5pt,varwidth
]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{   compat=1.16}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}

    % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    % Coordinate extraction (from tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420498/extract-convert-store-and-reuse-x-y-coordinate-components/426245#426245)
    % #1: node name
    % #2: output macro name: x coordinate
    % #3: output macro name: y coordinate
    \newcommand{\Getxycoords}[3]{%
        \pgfplotsextra{%
            % using `\pgfplotspointgetcoordinates' stores the (axis)
            % coordinates in `data point' which then can be called by
            % `\pgfkeysvalueof' or `\pgfkeysgetvalue'
            \pgfplotspointgetcoordinates{(#1)}%
            % `\global' (a TeX macro and not a TikZ/PGFPlots one) allows to
            % store the values globally
             \global\pgfkeysgetvalue{/data point/x}{#2}%
             \global\pgfkeysgetvalue{/data point/y}{#3}%
         }%
    }
    % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=80,ymin=0,ymax=80]
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i/\j in {
        1 / a,
        2 / b,
        3 / c
    }{
        \edef\temp{%
            \noexpand%
            \node [circle,inner sep=2pt,circle,fill,label=above:\j]  (d\j) at (axis cs:\i*10,\i*20+5) {};%
        }
        \temp
    }

    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \j in { a, b, c}{
        \Getxycoords{d\j}{\X\j}{\Y\j};
    }
\end{axis}
\node[below] (test) at (dc) {\Xc};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in `! Package pgf Error: No shape named dc is known.`

I also tried

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{a, b, c}{
    \Getxycoords{d#1}{\X#1}{\Y#1};
}
```

which gives:
`! Package pgf Error: No shape named da is known.` (and so on for db and dc.)

I'm guessing this has to do with when things get expanded or not, but I'm utterly confused on the subject.

Comment: Yes. Any reason why you want to read off the coordinates before `\end{axis}`?

Comment: Mmm, I think there might be use-cases where I need to use those coordinates in the same axis environment. But happy to see a solution without, to start with!

Comment: In your code there are several things that are not quite right. For instance, in `\Getxycoords{d\j}{\X\j}{\Y\j}` `\X\j` does *not* evaluate to `\Xa` etc. But I would also be interested in a solution where I can read off absolute coordinates when the axis is in the make. Therefore +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proposal to extract the coordinates of any object, regardless of whether or not this is a pgfplots `axis`. Just let Ti*k*Z compute the coordinates (relative to the origin) and normalize it to those of the point `(1,1)` relative to the origin. (And I also define `\Xc` etc.)

```
\documentclass[
%border=5pt,varwidth
]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=80,ymin=0,ymax=80]
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \i/\j in {
        1 /a,
        2 /b,
        3 /c
    }{
        \edef\temp{%
            \noexpand\node [circle,inner sep=2pt,circle,fill,label=above:\j,alias={d\j}]  (d\j) at (axis cs:\i*10,\i*20+5) {};%
        }
        \temp
    }
 \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
 \coordinate (X) at (1,1);
\end{axis}
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \j in { a, b, c}{
       \path let \p1=($(d\j.center)-(O)$),\p2=($(X)-(O)$),\n1={\x1/\x2},\n2={\y1/\y2} in
        \pgfextra{\pgfmathparse{\n1}
        \xdef\X{\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{\n2}
        \xdef\Y{\pgfmathresult}};
        \typeout{\X,\Y}
        \expandafter\xdef\csname X\j\endcsname{\X}
        \expandafter\xdef\csname Y\j\endcsname{\Y}
    }

\node[below] (test) at (dc) {\Xc}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]