# issue with a circle using tikz,beamer and pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, slideshow

Im trying to make a circle like this
[image]

using the next code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
         
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = middle,
        xmin=-1, xmax=3, ymin=-1, ymax=7,
        axis equal,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        yticklabels={0,...,5},
        grid=both,
        ]
       \draw (axis cs: 1,4) circle [radius=sqrt(3)];
       \draw (1,4) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$\C_C$](z0) {};
       \draw[-stealth] (z0) -- (2.4,3) node[midway,above]{$\space\sqrt3$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but when I try to use the beamer class to build the same picture inside a column inside a frame it cant be compiled using pdflatex

```
   \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = middle,
        xmin=-1, xmax=3, ymin=-1, ymax=7,
        axis equal,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        yticklabels={0,...,5},
        grid=both,
        ]
        %\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] grid ;
        \draw (axis cs: 1,4) circle [radius=sqrt(3)]; 
        \draw (1,4) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$\C_C$](z0) {};
        \draw[-stealth] (z0) -- (2.4,3) node[midway,above]{$\space\sqrt3$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

That gives me two issues one is to find what prevents the compilation and the other is the circle is supposed to be centered in `(1,3)` but when this coordinates is used the center in the picture appears in `(1,2)` so it must be compensated using `\draw (axis cs: 1,4)`. What I'm missing in the code to compile and to assign coordinates?

**UPDATE**
As noted by abcdefg there was a undefined sequence in  \C after that it compile as
[image]

but the center is shifted where is supposed to be using the

```
    \draw (1,3) node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,label=below:$C$](z0) {};
```

and

```
yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4,5},
yticklabels={$\pgfmathprintnumber\tick$},
```

**UPDATE 2**
Well the center is right where is supposed to be, but the arrow isnt starting from the center, as I understand, it is defined the line to start in `z0` and go to `(2.4,3)` . So it can be explicit done by

```
\draw[-stealth] (1,3) -- (2.4,3) node[midway,above]{$\space\sqrt3$};
```

but even so it seems not to be working.

Comment: It complains that `\C` is not defined (because it is not defined).

Comment: Let me check the log

Comment: it says ! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \C , but then how must define it?

Comment: How would *I* know? You use an undefined command, and you need to define it to produce the output you want to get. For the current output you can just drop `\C_`.

Comment: BTW, the "strange" shifts are because you use `yticklabels={0,...,5},`, i.e. you mislabel the y ticks. You can use `yticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber\tick$},` or similar to get the "correct" y tick labels.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I addressed the \C_thing,  but I dont get how to do the ticks, Im updating the question

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243578/coordinate-transformations-pgfplots-to-and-from-pgf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something of this sort (perhaps with `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}` instead of `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = middle,
        xmin=-1, xmax=3, ymin=-1, ymax=7,
        axis equal,
        xlabel = {$x$},
        ylabel = {$y$},
        yticklabel={$\pgfmathprintnumber\tick$},
        grid=both,
        ]
        %\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin] grid ;
        \draw (1,3)  node[circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,label=below:{$C$}] (c0){}
             circle [radius={sqrt(3)}]; 
        \draw[-stealth] (c0) to[edge label={$\sqrt{3}$}] ++
        (axis direction cs:{sqrt(3)*cos(-45)},{sqrt(3)*sin(-45)}) ;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, thanks, thats it, even though I dont understand quite well the stealth options, perhaps Im checking the manual again, tikz isnt my forte.

Comment: @riccs_0x `stealth` is just the name of an arrow head.

Comment: of course, that's why this wasn't making sense to me.